# Getting full model object from a combobox in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

If I have a store backed combobox selection that fires an event under ExtJS 4, how do I go about getting the full object that is represented by that selection?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In general, you can use the [`findRecordByValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-findRecordByValue) method on the combobox:

```
combobox.on('change', function(combobox, newValue, oldValue) {

   // Get the old and the new records.
   // NOTE: The underlying store is not guaranteed to 
   //       contain an associated record.
   var oldRecord = combobox.findRecordByValue(oldValue);
   if (oldRecord) {
      // Do something...
   }

   var newRecord = combobox.findRecordByValue(newValue);
   if (newRecord) {
      // Do something...
   }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I am fairly new to extJS, what is the best practice here?

Comment: Good question.  At the risk of sounding cliché, it depends on your use case. I think there are 2 key things to keep in mind. First, the `select` event is a UI event, whereas the `change` event is a state change event. Second, a combobox *uses* its store to facilitate changing its underlying field value through the UI. As a result, the `select` event will *always* correspond to a record in the underlying store, but the `change` event may not.

Comment: Hmm I honestly don't know which answer to mark as correct, because, as you pointed out, the right answer depends on the use case.

Comment: `var data = combo.findRecordByValue(combo.getValue()).data;`

Comment: This method is documented as private in ExtJS 4.0.0 - 4.0.4. It is made public in ExtJS 4.0.5. You can still use it in the versions mentioned above, it is just not considered 'best practice'.

Answer (score 6):

Figured this out almost immediately after posting my question.

My problem was that I was binding to the wrong event, I was using 'change' instead of 'selection'.

The selection event gives you the record with the full object contained in it.

Comment: Be aware that the `select` event will only be triggered if the value changes because the user clicked an option on the list.  If `setValue` is called programmatically, only `change` will fire.